# Excel: Sum up N largest numbers in non-continous array of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am not that fluent in Excel, so my question is potentially very simple but nevertheless gives me a headache.

I have a speadsheet with two types of values. One absolute value, and one that is calculated as a percentage from this absolute value.

```
     A
1    10
2    0.1
3    20
4    0.2
5    30
6    0.3
7    40
8    0.4
9    50
10   0.5
```

In this example, the second value is 1% from the first value (e.g. 0.1 from 10). In my actual table these values differ and the numbers are random. The % fraction from the second value depends on some key etc. So this is a simplified representation for the sake of a minimal example.

I want to determine the sum of the largest 4 (out of 5) numbers, but only from those 1% (e.g. 0.1, not 10) values. The numbers are all below each other. Basically, i want to ignore the absolute numbers (e.g. 10) and only apply the relative (e.g. 0.1) numbers.

The LARGE function determines the largest n numbers and has the following format:

```
=SUM(LARGE(array, k))
```

The array represents a continuous range in the table. However, I need to throw in a selected set of fields. Is there a way to do this with set of cells?

In other words, if i use the array I have

```
=SUM(LARGE(A1:A10, {1,2,3,4}))
```

the algorithms will always pick up 20,30,40 and 50.

Ideally, I want something like this:

```
=SUM(LARGE(array(A2,A4,A6,A8,A10), {1,2,3,4}))
```

Help?

Comment: Is a number relative if and only if it is below 1.0?

Comment: No, only in this simplified example. There is no way to determine if a number is rel or abs, but what i do know is its cell position. In other words, i have a list of cells that I know I want to include.

Comment: So every other number is relative?

Comment: Ok, let us not focus so much on absolut or relative. I have groups of numbers, here one ir alwasy larger than the other (e.g. 80 and 0.5, or 50 and 1.6). The second number does NOT need to be below 1 (its not a probability), it just is smaller. All I want to do is to have a way to enter the array of LARGE as a non-continuous range, e.g. by listing manually 6 or 7 fields instead of a range.

Comment: If you want to list the fields manually, then the second solution that I gave which used the indirect function should work. Built-in array formulas don't seem to work with non-contiguous ranges. A VBA solution would be fairly natural

Comment: I added a VBA solution, and also tagged the question with VBA in case others have a better VBA solution.

Answer (score 0):

For your simplified example, suppose that B1:B4 contains the values 1,2,3,4. Then in C1:C4 enter the array formula:

```
{=LARGE(IF(MOD(ROW(A1:A10),2)=0,A1:A10,-1),B1:B4)}
```

Similarly, the formula

```
{=SUM(LARGE(IF(MOD(ROW(A1:A10),2)=0,A1:A10,-1),B1:B4))}
```

(using `Ctrl + Shift + Enter` to accept as an array formula)

will give you the sum of the top 4.

This assumes that the numbers are all positive. You can replace the `-1` in the formula by the min of all the values -1 if that assumption isn't valid.

Another approach, if the criteria for being a relative cell is too ad-hoc to be summarized by a simple formula but if you have a listing of the cells is to use the `Indirect` function:

[image]

In the above screenshot I have a listing of the cells containing the relative values. In `D1` I put the formula `=INDIRECT(C1)` and copied down. Then, the formula

```
=SUM(LARGE(D1:D5,{1,2,3,4}))
```

returns the desired sum.

There might be a way to dispense with the helper column, though the function `INDIRECT` seems to not play very nicely with array formulas.

On Edit: Here is a VBA solution:

```
'The following function returns the sum of the largest k
'elements in range R that are at the list of indices
'if indices is left blank, then the sum of
'the largest k in R is returned

Function SumLargest(R As Range, k As Long, ParamArray indices() As Variant) As Double
    Dim A As Variant
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    Dim sum As Double

    n = UBound(indices)
    If n = -1 Then
        For i = 1 To k
            sum = sum + Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(R, i)
        Next i
        SumLargest = sum
        Exit Function
    Else
        ReDim A(0 To n)
        For i = 0 To n
            A(i) = R.Cells(indices(i)).Value
        Next i
        For i = 1 To k
            sum = sum + Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(A, i)
        Next i
        SumLargest = sum
    End If
End Function
```

If you put this function in a standard code module then it can be used from the worksheet like:

```
=SumLargest(A1:A10,4,2,4,6,8,10)
```

this last returns the sum of the largest 4, drawn from the entries at 2,4,6,8,10

Answer (score 0):

Using your provided sample data, something like this regular formula (does not require array entry) should work for you because the percentages will always be less than or equal to 1:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LARGE((A1:A10<=1)*A1:A10,{1,2,3,4}))
```

If you want a more flexible way of grabbing the top N numbers, you can substitute the `{1,2,3,4}` with the `ROW()` function, like so:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LARGE((A1:A10<=1)*A1:A10,ROW(1:4)))
```

**EDIT**: If the only way to get relative values is if they are every other row, starting in row 2, you can use this formula instead:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LARGE(INDEX((MOD(ROW(A1:A10),2)=0)*A1:A10,),ROW(1:4)))
```

Comment: What does the `INDEX(X*A1:A10,)` do to make this work?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah It allows the `MOD` function to be calculated as an array, instead of only returning the first result, it will calculate it for each cell in the range provided to the `MOD` function